# How to calculate items in javascript array as one total price?

Tags: javascript

how do i add all items in array into one total price?

```
var array = ['900' , '200', '300']
array.forEach(function(value){
    alert(value)
})
```

Comment: ive tried the code i put in but cant figure out how to calculate it

Comment: Convert `value` to a number, then add it to a `total` variable.

Comment: `total += Number(value);`

Answer (score 2):

One issue is that your array is storing the numeric values as text.

If you have it like this, you can sum them up without having to convert to number:

```
var array = [900 , 200, 300]
```

The following would then work:

```
var sum = array.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your strings to a number using the ***Number()*** function... You can use a typical reduce function to add the current value with the summed values each iteration through the `reduce()` function...

```js
const arr = ['900' , '200', '300']

const sum = arr.reduce((acc, curVal) => {
  return Number(acc) + Number(curVal);
});

console.log(sum)
```